# Json schema not working

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Im trying to use json schema, here with a simple example.
Im using the site: http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Schema:

```
{ 
      'Foods':
      { 
        'type': 'array', 
        'items':
        {
          'GoodFoods': { 'type':'string' },
          'NastyFoods': { 'type':'string' },
          'BlendFoods': { 'type': 'string' }
        },      
        'required': ['BlendFoods'],
      }
}
```

Input JSON:

```
{
  "Foods": 
  [
      {
        "GoodFoods": "Pasta",
        "NastyFoods": true,

      }
  ]
}
```

The idea here is that it should complain that "BlendFoods" property is missing and that the NastyFoods is a boolean not a string. But instead it says "No errors found. JSON Validates against the schema". That is not what I want.

I tried so much with this but cant figure out what Im doing wrong in the schema, any ideas?

Best regards
Rob

Answer (score 5):

The corrected schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Foods": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "GoodFoods": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "NastyFoods": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "BlendFoods": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "BlendFoods"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please see [this site](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) for reference and help.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra comma after true.

try this:

```
  {
      "Foods": 
      [
          {
            "GoodFoods": "Pasta",
            "NastyFoods": true

          }
      ]
    }
```